# Find Analytic Function

Tags: complex-analysis

Is there an analytic function $f:\mathbb C\to \mathbb C$ such that$$f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) =\frac{1}{n} \qquad \text {and} \qquad   f\left(-\frac{1}{n} \right) =\frac{1}{n}? $$

Comment: Yes..I edited. Can you help me?

Comment: See the [Identity Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem).  It follows quickly from that that your function can not exist.

Comment: Thank you lulu...

Answer (score 9):

You can do this without any theorems at all: clearly $f(0)=0$ due to continuity - but then what's the derivative of $f$ at zero? Well, it's the limit
$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(h)}h$$
However, at $h=1/n$ this quotient is $1$ and at $h=-1/n$, this quotient is $-1$, hence this limit does not exist, so $f$ is not differentiable at $0$.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that $f$ exists. Consider $g(z)=z$ and note that $g(\frac{1}{n})=\frac{1}{n}=f(\frac{1}{n})$ by hypothesis. As $f=g$ in a set with zero as an accumulation point in $\mathbb{C}$, by the Identity Theorem applied to $\mathbb{C}$ (which is connected), $f(z)=g(z)\,\forall z\in\mathbb{C}$. But $f(-\frac{1}{n})=g(-\frac{1}{n})=-\frac{1}{n}\neq\frac{1}{n}$ so $f$ such that the two conditions happen can not exist.